# How to save mp4 format using default camera using video recorder

Tags: android

I am recording a video using the default camera. It saves in the 3gp format. Can anybody tell me how to save it in an mp4 format or how to convert 3gp to mp4 and save it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following link.I think it will help you.

http://androidforums.com/htc-evo-4g/115710-evo-records-3gp-how-convert.html